# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc

i have published my asp.net MVC 3 web application locally using IIS 7 express and visual developer express 2010, but when i tired to login to the application and after i insert the user name and password on the login view the following error was returned:-

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed.
```

so what might be causing this problme? 
the current connection string is :-

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ElearningEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Elearning.csdl|res://*/Models.Elearning.ssdl|res://*/Models.Elearning.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MScProject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/527bf46a-b3fe-4ae6-8b41-eb40024399c8/) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/fbf32aa8-2125-4919-be81-3baa399e2e0d)?